# ROS2: Record two rosbags at a time - snapshot and continous - and control it via service

Tags: ros2, rosbag2

i want to trigger several rosbag records from a node and wonder what is the best way to do it. I know that there is a tutorial about recording from a node but i think the described way is not the best if you have something like 50 topics and you have to subscribe to all of them. It is also much afford to maintain it if there are changes. Also i failed to adapt the tutorial to take snapshot record.

So here is what i want to do:
I want to record several bags at the same time on different triggers. I have a topic with these triggers:

- start a "normal" record of all topics
- take a snapshot of all topics

For separate records,  my solution is to start a recorder on system start with

ros2 bag record -a --start-paused

or

ros2 bag record -a --max-cache-size 12345 --snapshot-mode

and in a c++ node i make a system call on the trigger in a callback function, for example

```
if(snapshot_trigger)
{
   std::system("ros2 service call /rosbag2_recorder/snapshot rosbag2_interfaces/srv/Snapshot");
}
```

or

```
if(record_trigger)
{
   std::system("ros2 service call /rosbag2_recorder/resume rosbag2_interfaces/srv/Resume");
}
```

Now, I am wondering if there is a way to do both at the same time. For example there comes a trigger for a normal recording and during this record, there comes another trigger for a snapshot. I just tried to start two records, but of cause this does not work, all service calls have been reacted to by the second started recorder...

So has anybody here an idea how to implement this usecase?

Thank you!

Jens